# How to consume Spring Hateoas CollectionModel using WebClient?

Tags: spring, webclient, hateoas

I figued out how to consume an EntityModel, but so far am unable to consume a CollectionModel (Spring code is using Groovy)

My Class:

```
@Relation(value = "person", collectionRelation = "people")
class Person {
  long id
  String firstName
  String lastName
}
```

My Controller:

```
CollectionModel<Person> getPeople() {
    Person person = new Person(
            id: 2L,
            firstName: 'Mark',
            lastName: 'Hamil'
    )
    Collection<Person> people = Collections.singleton(person)
    CollectionModel.of(people)
  }
```

Then I created a service to consume the output of the controller:

```
CollectionModel<Person> model= this.webClient.get().uri('localhost:8080/api/people')
                  .retrieve()
                  .bodyToMono(new TypeReferences.CollectionModelType<Person>())
                  .block()

          List<Person> people = model.content
```

But the model is blank.  I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Here is the raw output of localhost:8080/api/people

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "people": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "Mark",
            "lastName": "Hamil"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @Clark, how do get total records and current page size from `CollectionModel`?

Answer (score 1):

After posting over at https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-hateoas# and getting some insight, I was able to get this working. Note this is using Groovy.

First, in the controller I made sure the produces was set for hal:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/hal+json")
    CollectionModel<Person> getPeople() {
       Link link = linkTo(PersonController).withSelfRel()
       List<EntityModel> entityModelList = [this.getPerson()]
    }
```

Where `this.getPerson()` is:

```
EntityModel<Person> getPerson() {
    Person person = new Person(
      id: 2L,
      firstName: 'Mark',
      lastName: 'Hamil'
    )
    Link link = linkTo(PersonController).slash(person.id).withSelfRel()
    EntityModel<Person> personEntityModel = EntityModel.of(person, link)

    personEntityModel
  }
```

Then in the calling api:

```
    Mono<CollectionModel<EntityModel<Person>>> personCollectionModel = this.webClient
       .get()
       .uri('localhost:8080/uswf-api/people')
       .accept(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON)
       .exchange()
       .flatMap { response ->
           if (response.statusCode().isError()) {
              System.out.println('Error')
        } else {
          response.bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<CollectionModel<EntityModel<Person>>>() {})
        }
    }
```

Then I can use this result by subscribing to the result:

```
personCollectionModel.subscribe( { collectionModel -> collectionModel.content })
```